# Google App Engine & PHP write file

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to develop using Google App Engine.

I am trying to write data into a text file.

Initially, my php codes were like this:

```
function putFile($nstr,$fn){

 $filename = $fn;
 $file = fopen( $filename, "w" );




 if( $file == false )
{
  echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
  exit();
}
fwrite( $file, $nstr );
fclose( $file );

}
```

I run the GAE Launcher and visited http://localhost:9080

There were error messages shown:

*Warning:  The local filesystem is readonly, open failed 
Warning:  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ....
Error in opening new file*

After this, I changed my codes slightly to see If I could resolve the problem on my own...

New codes:

```
function putFile($nstr,$fn){

 $filename = $fn;

 $file = fopen( 'gs://#default#/'.$filename, "w" );

  if( $file == false )
  {
     echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
     exit();
  }
  fwrite( $file, $nstr );
  fclose( $file );

   }
```

I run the app again. There were no error messages shown at all.

*However there is no changes to my text file.*

I don't understand my mistake.

- Did I write the codes wrongly?
- Is this something related to file permissions?
- Maybe I don't understand how GAE works in terms of file read write?

Comment: Your code looks correct. What exactly are you using to determine that "text file" (which actually is not one -- it's a Google Cloud Storage object) has not changed -- `gsutil cat gs://your-app-id.appspot.com/the_filename`, or what else?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are running this from the GAE Launcher and visiting `http://localhost:9080/`, I assume you're encountering this error when testing with the development server on your local machine. The development environment mimics the production environment by writing to the local file system.

The article entitled [The php.ini File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini#GAE_directives) says the following about PHP application privileges in the local development environment:

> By default PHP applications are not allowed to write to the filesystem.

According to [this response](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11729#c3) to public issue [11729](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11729), this feature was added in version **1.9.18** of the App Engine SDK, though not mentioned in the related [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.9.18_-_February_19,_2015).

Setting **`google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem`** to **`1`** in your **`php.ini`** file should lift this restriction albeit only for your development environment. Barring this, the issue may